# I want to create mobile app to just redirect to a website, is this even possible?

Tags: react-native, flutter, ionic-framework

I want to have react native app to just redirect to a website. For example, I have just a mobile app, and after you download and you just open that app just sends you to the website. So is this possible with react native or some other hybrid platform like a flutter or ionic?

Comment: It's possible but Apple will reject it as having no functionality. You could probably put it on the play store.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is that easy to make?

Comment: Yes, but what I am saying is "don't bother". Apple won't publish it.  Google probably will but it is still a pointless app.

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you would need to have a mobile app for this? I assume that users are going to find your app by visiting your website. So if they wanted to return, couldn't they just access your website directly?

Comment: @itsanewabstract Actually I wanted just to make it easier for my potential users.  Just to have like a shortcut of the website on their phone. I don't know is that a good idea anyway

Comment: Android has support for bookmarks of websites on your home screen. Maybe this is the better option.

Comment: @josxha Thank you for an answer, that is one of solution for this or I can just put an option for users to download this app directly from my website, but they will be sceptical for sure

Comment: @Vesko_dev That makes sense. In that case, I would look into building a Progressive Web App (PWA). You can configure it so that users can install your web app on their phones and use it as if it were a native app. Then you don't have to worry about react native or publishing to the app stores

Comment: @itsanewabstract I will definitely check PWA, thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can also add a guidelines on adding a web page to your home screen on iOS to your website

Answer (score 1):

As already explained in comments, the chances that such an app will be included in the stores are close to zero. But I just asked myself how many lines of code you can put in such an app. More like this as proof. Here is my result of the complete app:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  launch("https://google.com/");
  exit(0);
}
```

I have written the app in flutter and uses the package [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to open the url.